# Problem with importing file into databricks notebook

Tags: scala, apache-spark, import, databricks, txt

I'm trying to import a .txt file from my local computer into a databricks notebook (scala). I go into the data section and click "add data". The "upload file" option is selected in the top panel, I click browse to find the file and then "Create table in Notebook". I then get a path to the file but when I try to access the data in another notebook through the command "val file_location = "/FileStore/tables/....txt" I get a "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /FileStore/tables/....txt (No such file or directory)". Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here and what I should do instead?

Kind regards

Comment: It seems like it can't read .txt files. If I change the line spark.read.format("txt") to spark.read.format("csv") it can find the data (but then it is loaded as a csv-file which is not what I want).

Answer (score 0):

Format should be `text`, not `txt`.  See the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#manually-specifying-options):

```scala
scala> val df = spark.read.format("text").load("README.md")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> df.count
res0: Long = 104
```

Or you can use `spark.read.textFile` function that is really shortcut for that:

```scala
scala> spark.read.textFile("README.md").count
res1: Long = 104
```